# Best way to create a fake smart pointer when you need one but only have a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

What's the best way to fake a shared pointer for situations like below where you know it's ok?

```
#include <memory>

struct Target {
    bool ok() { return true; }
};

struct Monitor {
    // Take a shared pointer as we will be using it later
    Monitor(std::shared_ptr<Target> target)
        : target(target)
    { }

    bool check() {
        // Use the shared pointer we grabbed before
        return this->target->ok();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Target> target;
};

// This function does not take a shared pointer because it does not
// hold on to the object after returning.
bool checkTargetOnce(Target& t)
{
    // We have to pass a shared_ptr to Monitor() because it wants to
    // keep a copy after the constructor returns.  But we know in this
    // case the Monitor instance won't be used after we return, so we
    // don't need a shared_ptr here - but we have to supply one anyway.

    Monitor m(t); // What should be put here?

    return m.check();
}

int main(void)
{
    Target t;
    checkTargetOnce(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you control the definition of `Target` you can inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and then use `shared_from_this()` to make a `shared_ptr` to an existing instance.

Comment: This is why I don't condone using a `shared_ptr` in public interfaces. It's usually not necessary and it leads to complications like this.

Comment: If you pursue a `std::enable_shared_from_this` derivation of `Target`, the actual `Target&` *must* refer to an object owned by at least one `std::shared_ptr<>` *already*. Thats important. [Read more here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: @MarkRansom: How would you handle it when an object needs to keep using a resource after the constructor returns, which you also need to keep using yourself?  Taking a `shared_ptr` is recommended by Herb Sutter in this situation (see [GotW 91, solution 3e](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/))

Comment: If you need to keep the resource, then passing it something that you don't have a `shared_ptr` for already is just asking for trouble. You have a bad design that you need to fix.

Comment: Well the only other option is to pass the resource to every single function in the class each time it's called, instead of having it stored by the constructor.  I'm not sure that's such a great solution either.

Comment: Well, the question is really should the user be expected to ensure that a monitor doesn't outlive its target, or is it impractical or impossible and so shared ownership must be taken? There are all sorts of classes in the standard library that stores a simple non-owning raw pointer to something else, expecting the user to ensure that the relevant objects are not destroyed prematurely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After punching the person who put a `shared_ptr` there<sup>*</sup>, use the crazy (ok, *aliasing*) constructor of `shared_ptr`:

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

This constructs a `shared_ptr` sharing ownership with `r` but holds the pointer `ptr`. Now we can in turn make `r` a `shared_ptr` that owns nothing, i.e.

```
Monitor m(std::shared_ptr<Target>(std::shared_ptr<Target>(), &t));
```

Compared to the naive approach of using a no-op deleter, this is guaranteed `noexcept`, and has less overhead as it does not allocate a reference counting block.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> This step is optional.</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by "does not allocate a reference counting block"?  Doesn't it still count references, just against the empty object instead?

Comment: @Malvineous A default-constructed `shared_ptr` has no reference counting block. A `shared_ptr` constructed using the aliasing constructor and a default-constructed `shared_ptr` also has no reference counting block - it owns nothing, so why bother counting?